# Transitive project dependencies not found

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a flat project hierarchy with 4 projects. Lets call them B,C,D,M and they have the following linear dependencies :

B -> C -> M -> D

-> = "depends on"

Projects B,C and M have a build.gradle and settings.gradle. The settings.gradle always does a includeFlat on all dependent projects. In case of B would that be includeFlat('D', 'M', 'C').
The build.gradle defines the always defines the dependency to the project it depends on. In case of B that would be compile project('C').

If I try to build project B I run into the problem that after parsing B, gradle tries to parse the build.gradle of C and fails because it can't find M.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':C'.
> Project with path 'M' could not be found in project ':C'.
```

I think the relevant part of the debug output is:

```
Included projects: [root project 'B', project ':C', project ':D', project ':M']
```

It seems gradle sorts the include in alphabetical order, despite what is defined in the other settings.gradle  files and in the build.gradle dependencies.

When I created C I also wondered why I need to include D into the includeFlat settings. But there it works because it orders the includes to D,M.

The only "solution" I currently see is that I remove the project dependencies in B and depend on the build jar of C. But this has the huge (game breaking) disadvantage, that when I change something in D I need a full build, publish and "refresh from nexus" cycle till the changes are visible. Because C, M and D are still in active development this isn't an option.

To fix that I would need to tell the eclipse plugin that when it discovers a jar dependency that is also an project that it adds a project dependency to the classpath instead of the jar dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some misconceptions about how Gradle multi-project builds work. Here are some facts that might help you understand what's going on:

- A Gradle build can only have a single `settings.gradle`.
- The order of `include` statements in `settings.gradle` has no relevance.
- Execution dependencies are always between tasks, not between projects. For example, depending on `project(":M")` is shorthand for depending on the `default` configuration of that project. Gradle translates this into a dependency on those tasks in M that are responsible for building the artifacts of its `default` configuration. Note that depending on a project does *not* mean that all tasks in that project will be run before any task in the depending project.
- A multi-project build has a *logical* project hierarchy. `":M"` is an *absolute* project path (`:` denotes the root project), whereas `"M"` is a *relative* project path. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current project.

To get a more in-depth understanding of multi-project builds, I recommend to study the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the multi-project build samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Thanks again for clearing things up. I read the relevant chapters multiple times, but I find they are less clear then the other chapters and missing information, like that you can only have a single settings.gradle. For example, "7.3.3. Dependencies between projects" makes it sound like only the jar is imported. Also I would prefer more "real life" examples in chapter 55 instead of the marine life example. Maybe it would better to speak of a composition of projects when explaining Multi-projects build. When talking about dependencies it is easy to think they behave like external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The whole mess was caused by a missing ':'. Gradle seems to differentiate between 
`compile project('M')` and `compile project(':M')`, when the project (in this case the line was in the C) is included by an other project. Just building C works fine with both version.
`gradle projects` returns the same tree for project C in both cases.

I can't explain what exactly is the difference and I hope someone can explain it to me.

Comment: 'M' is a relative path, so it depends on the file you used that in. ':' specifies the root, so ':M' is an absolute path starting from the root project and specifies the direct child of the root project with name M.